# Hibernate Transaction Manager Issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and attempting to run a java/spring example that retrieves data from a table in MS SqlServer.  Everytime I try to run the program, the data source loads ok. But when spring tries to load the session facotry it gets the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' 
        defined in class path resource [ml/spring/src/applicationContext.xml]: 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
```

Below is the application Context file I am using:

```
<!-- Data source bean -->
<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"  >
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver</value></property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://machine:port</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>user</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>password</value></property>
</bean>

<!--  Session Factory Bean -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>authors.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=net.sf.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
        </value>
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I've been looking at a similar problem. I will post if I can solve mine, but I'm like you, don't know much about hibernate.

Comment: Just a comment - you can reduce the verbosity of your xml by relpacing <property name="foo"><value>bar</value></property> with <property name="foo" value="bar" /> or perhaps even p:foo="bar" if you use the 'p' namespace supported by spring.

Answer (score 14):

You are missing a JAR file containing the JTA API classes. You probably have one already when you downloaded Hibernate. It should be called something like:

```
jta-1.1.jar
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using maven, use [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/jta/1.1),

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```